# Manual ArcLength sampling on spline differs from MeshFunction sampling

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, splines, mesh

Using [Michael E2's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55322), I performed a manual arclength parameterisation by solving the differential equation (or: finding the inverse of a function whose derivative is known).

I compared the results with the built-in arclength mesh-sampling. Unexpectedly, they are not the same (see green and red points on plot).

Using the built-in function is no solution to this problem, because I need this method for some other sampling based on specific parameterisations (other than arclength).

Here's the code:

```
ptsp = {{0, 0}, {0, 2}, {3, 2}, {1, -2}, {4, -2}, {4, 0}};
g = BSplineFunction[ptsp, SplineWeights -> {1, 1, 15, 15, 1, 1}, SplineDegree -> 3];

ClearAll[s, t];
dg[t_?NumericQ] := If[t - 1. <= 0, g'[t], g'[1]];
tfn = NDSolveValue[{t'[s] == 1/Norm[dg[t[s]]], t[0] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[t[s] == 1, "StopIntegration"]}, 
   t, {s, 0, 1 + NIntegrate[Norm[g'[t]], {t, 0, 1}]}];


ParametricPlot[g[t], {t, 0, 1}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}, Mesh -> {20-1}, 
 MeshStyle -> {PointSize[0.015], Green}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black} 
 Epilog -> {
   PointSize[0.013], Red, 
   Point[g /@ 
     tfn[Rescale[Range[0, 1, 1/20], {0, 1}, First@tfn["Domain"]]]],
   PointSize[0.01], Gray, Point[g /@ Range[0, 1, 1/20]]
 }
]
```

I also tried other methods, like [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8456), which gave the same wrong result.

Does anyone have an idea why this happens for this specific B-Spline?

[image: resulting plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that the derivative of `BSplineFunction` is incorrect when using weights (see [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30790/bsplinefunction-derivatives-wrong-if-using-weights)), as can be seen from the following comparison:

```
Plot[
 {
  Norm[g[s] - g[s - 0.001]]/0.001,
  Norm[g'[s]]
  },
 {s, 0, 9},
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotLegends -> {"\!\(\*FractionBox[\(\(|\)\(g \((s)\) - g \((s - \
0.001)\)\)\(|\)\), \(0.001\)]\)", "|g'(s)|"}
 ]
```

[image]

Using the same crude manual derivative for the original code produces the expected result:

ptsp = {{0, 0}, {0, 2}, {3, 2}, {1, -2}, {4, -2}, {4, 0}};
g = BSplineFunction[ptsp, SplineWeights -> {1, 1, 15, 15, 1, 1}, 
   SplineDegree -> 3];

```
ClearAll[s, t];
d = 0.0001;
dg[t_?NumericQ] := 
  If[t < 1. - d, (g[t + d] - g[t])/d, (g[1] - g[1 - d])/d];
tfn = NDSolveValue[{t'[s] == 1/Norm[dg[t[s]]], t[0] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[t[s] == 1, "StopIntegration"]}, 
   t, {s, 0, 1 + NIntegrate[Norm[dg[t]], {t, 0, 1}]}];


ParametricPlot[g[t], {t, 0, 1}, MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}, 
 Mesh -> {20 - 1}, MeshStyle -> {PointSize[0.015], Green}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[0.01], Red, 
   Point[g /@ 
     Clip@tfn[
       Rescale[Range[0, 1, 1/20], {0, 1}, First@tfn["Domain"]]]], 
   PointSize[0.01], Gray, Point[g /@ Range[0, 1, 1/20]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh man, who would have thought about a bug in the underlying Mathematica functions. Thanks!!

Comment: I noticed in the specified range for the numerical integration you still use ```g'```. That should be ```dg``` as well, I think.

Comment: Yes, that was an oversight from my side - thank you for pointing it out, I've corrected it now

Answer (score 3):

Here's another alternative, based on manually building the weighted B-spline from `BSplineBasis[]` (similar to what was done [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88013)):

```
deg = 3;
pts = {{0, 0}, {0, 2}, {3, 2}, {1, -2}, {4, -2}, {4, 0}};
wts = {1, 1, 15, 15, 1, 1};

knots = ArrayPad[Subdivide[deg], deg, "Fixed"];

xf[t_] = (pts[[All, 1]].(wts Table[BSplineBasis[{deg, knots}, j - 1, t],
                                   {j, Length[pts]}]))/
         (wts.Table[BSplineBasis[{deg, knots}, j - 1, t], {j, Length[pts]}]);
yf[t_] = (pts[[All, 2]].(wts Table[BSplineBasis[{deg, knots}, j - 1, t],
                                   {j, Length[pts]}]))/
         (wts.Table[BSplineBasis[{deg, knots}, j - 1, t], {j, Length[pts]}]);
```

Check:

```
gg = BSplineFunction[pts, SplineWeights -> wts, SplineDegree -> deg];

ParametricPlot[{gg[t], {xf[t], yf[t]}}, {t, 0, 1}, 
               PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[7], AbsoluteThickness[3]}]
```

[image: check weighted spline]

Then, using the method from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8455), generate the parameter values corresponding to the equispaced points:

```
arc = NDSolveValue[{s'[t] == Sqrt[xf'[t]^2 + yf'[t]^2], s[0] == 0}, 
                   s, {t, 0, 1}, Method -> "Extrapolation"];

end = arc[1];

With[{n = 21},
     tvals = (\[FormalT] /. FindRoot[arc[\[FormalT]] == end #,
                                     {\[FormalT], #, 0, 1}]) & /@ Subdivide[n]];
```

Check that the corresponding points are indeed equispaced:

```
Max[Abs[Differences[arc[tvals], 2]]] // Chop
   0
```

Generate and visualize the points:

```
Legended[ParametricPlot[{xf[t], yf[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, 
                         Epilog -> {Directive[AbsolutePointSize[5], ColorData[97, 4]], 
                                    Point[Transpose[{xf /@ tvals, yf /@ tvals}]]}, 
                         MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}, Mesh -> {20}, 
                         MeshStyle -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[7], ColorData[97, 3]]], 
         PointLegend[{Directive[AbsolutePointSize[7], ColorData[97, 3]], 
                      Directive[AbsolutePointSize[5], ColorData[97, 4]]},
                     {"MeshFunctions \[Rule] \"ArcLength\"", 
                      "manually computed"}]]
```

[image: equispaced points on a weighted B-spline]

Comment: I think you have an off-by-one-error in there - if you use `Mesh -> {20}`, the points overlap perfectly (`With[{n = 20}, tvals = …]` also works of course). I would be pretty surprised if `MeshFunctions->"ArcLength"` didn't work only for some specific functions (assuming that it performs the relevant computations on the numeric result it got from plotting the function, and doesn't use some analytic method)

Comment: Well but it looks like this difference is just due to an unequal number of subdivisions. In fact if you use ```Mesh -> {20}``` everything's good. (LL you won for 10 seconds!)

Comment: @johk95 That's what I would call perfect timing ;)

Comment: @Lukas and johk95, thanks for catching that; I've fixed it.