# Coordinates of spline plot using ArcLength mesh function

Tags: splines

The following code produces a 3D spline with equidistant interpolation points:

```
Needs["Splines`"];
f = SplineFit[{{0, 0, 3}, {2, 0, 3}, {2, 2, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}, Cubic];
plot = ParametricPlot3D[f[t], {t, 0, 3}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}, Mesh -> {15}, 
  MeshStyle -> {PointSize[0.02], Red}]
```

[image]

How do I get the actual coordinates (list of points) of the red points?
(they must be equidistant as in the plot).

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Generating evenly spaced points on a curve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8454/generating-evenly-spaced-points-on-a-curve)? Also: [How to get a uniformly distributed list of points from a B-spline function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54841/how-to-get-a-uniformly-distributed-list-of-points-from-a-b-spline-function/55322) and [Manual ArcLength sampling on spline differs ...](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214061/manual-arclength-sampling-on-spline-differs-from-meshfunction-sampling)

Comment: Not really. Two cases are 2D, and 3D does not work. One case does not return coordinates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Needs["Splines`"];

f = SplineFit[{{0, 0, 3}, {2, 0, 3}, {2, 2, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}, Cubic];

plot = ParametricPlot3D[f[t], {t, 0, 3}, MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}, 
  Mesh -> {15}, MeshStyle -> {PointSize[0.02], Red},
  WorkingPrecision -> 15]
```

The red dots are located at

```
pts = Cases[plot // Normal, Point[pt_] :> pt, Infinity];

Length@pts

(* 15 *)
```

The red dots are ordered as

```
orderedPts = Rest@pts[[FindCurvePath[pts][[1]]]];
```

**EDIT:** Or more robustly,

```
orderedPts = Rest@pts[[FindShortestTour[pts][[2]]]]
```

They are approximately equally spaced (note that the curve length between points is not the same as the [`EucldeanDistance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EucldeanDistance.html) between them)

```
dist = EuclideanDistance @@@ Partition[orderedPts, 2, 1]

(* {0.483212, 0.482984, 0.481793, 0.477275, 0.478571, 0.482301, 0.482944, \
0.483029, 0.482915, 0.482403, 0.47809, 0.474605, 0.481376, 0.482977} *)

{Mean[dist], StandardDeviation[dist]}

(* {0.481034, 0.00274354} *)
```

Comment: Thanks! I do not need exactly equal spacing, this is perfect.

Comment: The ordering does not quite work, e.g. for points {{-5, -2.2, 0.7}, {5, -4.5, 10}, {6.7, -9.5, 5}, {-2, -0.5, -1.5}}

Comment: For the ordering use `orderedPts = Rest@pts[[FindShortestTour[pts][[2]]]];`

Answer (score 4):

From your plot you can extract the points. However, the points are given as indices of a list of coordinates. To get these indices:

```
indices = Cases[(plot // FullForm ) , Point[x_] -> x, Infinity][[1]];
```

Next we need to extract the list of coordinates:

```
coord = Cases[plot, GraphicsComplex[x_, _] -> x, Infinity][[1]];
```

From this list we only need to coordinates indicated by "indices:"

```
coord = coord[[indices]];
```

To test if everything works, we may plot large opaque green points over the original plot:

```
Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.3], Green, PointSize[0.05], 
   Point[coord]}], plot]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

- Since `MaxRecursion` will automatic add extra points to make the curve smooth,  we need to set

```
MaxRecursion->0
```

to prevent such feature, keep the order of meshs.(to make the curve smooth, now we have to set `PlotPoints -> 100`.)

```
Clear[plot0]; 
Needs["Splines`"];
f = SplineFit[{{0, 0, 3}, {2, 0, 3}, {2, 2, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}, Cubic];
plot0 = 
 ParametricPlot3D[f[t], {t, 0, 3}, MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}, 
  Mesh -> {15}, MeshStyle -> {PointSize[0.02], Red}, 
  MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotPoints -> 100];
meshs = Cases[Normal@plot0, Point[pts_] :> pts, -1];
Graphics3D[{MapIndexed[{Red, Text[First@#2, #1, {-1, -1}], Blue, 
     Point[#1]} &, meshs]}]
```

[image]